# what does php use if multiple MTAs are installed?

Tags: php, mta

I'm just wondering what happens if I have sendmail installed, and subsequently installed postfix, what will php use when I use the `mail` command?

Will having 2 MTAs installed cause any other problems? I'm very new at this, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple MTAs installed, only one can provide `/usr/sbin/sendmail` at a time. You can set the path to the MTA in the `php.ini`, by the `sendmail_path` option, in case it's installed somewhere else, or you want to use it with different parameters than the default. If you install postfix, sendmail will be removed and postfix will provide `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured via php.ini but by default it will use `sendmail` Most MTAs replace the sendmail binary with their own copy, so whatever package is providing the sendmail binary is the one that php is using, providing you made no config changes.

As a side not do not install multiple MTAs. There's almost no away they will all work.